# How to display the_meta() of a Wordpress custom page in a table

Tags: wordpress

I have some meta values on my wordpress custom page that I need to be displayed in a table. Is there any way I can do that.

Here's the code I'm using now: `<?php the_meta(); ?>`

And this is what it shows:

[image]

I want to do something like:

[image]

I found out that:

> the_meta() is located in wp-includes/post-template.php

This makes the output:

```
<ul class='post-meta'>
<li><span class='post-meta-key'>your_key:</span> your_value</li>
</ul>
```

So it's not recommended to edit files in that folder because of the wordpress update.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
<tr><td colspan="2">Game Summary</td></tr>
<?php 
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() ); 
$exclude = array('_edit_last', '_wp_page_template', '_edit_lock');
foreach( $meta as $key => $value ) {
    if( in_array( $key, $exclude) )
        continue;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value[0]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! The key appears but it doesn't show the values, it shows "Array".

Comment: Replace this: <td><?php echo $value[0]; ?></td>

Comment: Now it works but it shows some rows above: _edit_last, _wp_page_template, _edit_lock; all 3 with a value. Can u tell how I can get rid of them?